# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer displays correctly except on iPhone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, avcapturesession

I'm working on implementing a view that consists of an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. The view is supposed to take up the entirety of the screen, except for the navigation bar at the top (the view is embedded in a navigation controller).

My code below shows how I've set up a capture session and added the front camera as input if it's available.

```
//Set up capture Session
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

//Add a camera as input if we have a front-facing camera available
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
        //Set our input
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
        [session addInput:input];
        if (!input) {
            NSLog(@"No Input");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is where the output is configured, and the camera output view is added as a subview, with the frame determined by the view's bounds.

```
//Output
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];
output.videoSettings = @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };

//Preview Layer
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

As you can see in the screenshot below when running on an iPhone 6, the preview layer does not take up the entirety of the screen (the white space to the right of the camera view and under the navigation bar should be filled up by the preview layer):

[image]

However, it does fill up the screen appropriately on the iPhone 5 screenshot below (as well as the iPhone 4, 4S, and 5S). Does anyone have any insight into why?

[image]

Comment: First thing I would check by logging, breakpoint or "Debug View Hierarchy" is if at the time of adding your preview layer `self.view` actually has the bounds you're expecting it to have. To me it looks a lot like the UIView itself could be fixed to a width of 320, e.g. by having its frame set somewhere in code or by Auto Layout constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're creating this video preview layer in `viewDidLoad`, the view controller's view has not been laid out yet, and as such its `frame` and `bounds` are not necessarily what they will be once the view is shown on screen. You'll have to wait until the view is laid out to set the correct frame of your preview layer, which you can do by implementing the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller, like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

This ensures that any time your view controller's view changes in size, your preview layer also changes in size.

Comment: That makes sense. I was creating the video preview in a separate `createAVSessionAndCameraOutput` method, which I was calling from `viewDidLoad`. I'll try calling `createAVSessionAndCameraOutput from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead and see how that goes.

Comment: @narner Okay! Make sure you don't end up creating and adding multiple `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`s to your view's layer though, as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can get called more than once.

Comment: Ah! I see. Would a better strategy be to create the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in `viewDidLoad` and then set the position in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @narner Yep! That's what I would suggest at least. Do the creation exactly one time, and then just update the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as the backing layer of a `UIView` subclass, and then add an instance of this view as a subview to your view controller's view. This way you can use constraints to position your video capture preview however you want, as you would with any other view.

Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
// MyCaptureVideoPreviewView.h

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MyCaptureVideoPreviewView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *layer;
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame session:(AVCaptureSession *)session;

@end


// MyCaptureVideoPreviewView.m

@implementation MyCaptureVideoPreviewView

@dynamic layer;

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class];
}

- (AVCaptureSession *)session {
    return self.layer.session;
}

- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    self.layer.session = session;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame session:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.session = session;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And then somewhere in your view controller's implementation:

```
MyCaptureVideoPreviewView *previewView = [[MyCaptureVideoPreviewView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                                                                  session:session];
previewView.layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:previewView];

// Add whatever constraints you want. Here we just match the superview's bounds:
NSArray *vConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[previewView]|" options:kNilOptions
                                                                metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previewView)];
NSArray *hConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[previewView]|" options:kNilOptions
                                                                metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previewView)];

[self.view addConstraints:vConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:hConstraints];
```